# How to share .NET assemblies among multiple applications?

Tags: .net, dll

I have few vb.Net application which has bunch of similar Library dll's as well. Now i am trying to isolate the library dll's into a single folder and invoke the individual applications by linking the Common library dll.

after researching the below DLL search order for invoking the application,

1. DLL's in Parent directory(usually Debug/Release folder)
2. GAC
3. Directory mentioned in the "Path" System Environmental variable.

so, i have mentioned the common library folder path in the environmental variable and tried invoking the application. as soon as launched , the below error is encountered

> Description:   Stopped working
>
> Problem signature:
>   Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
>   Application Name: Sample.exe
>   Application Version:  1.0.0.0
>   Application Timestamp: 58e5cc85
>   Fault Module Name: KERNELBASE.dll
>   Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.18015
>   Fault Module Timestamp:   50b83c8a
>   Exception Code:   e0434f4d
>   Exception Offset: 0000c41f
>   OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.18.10
>   Locale ID:    1033

Kindly let me know on how to debug the issue and fix this issue? I suspect that the libraries are not getting linked and so we get this error.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Let me restate the problem to make sure we on same page. I assume you have multiple applications/programs and all those apps reference/use some DLLs which are common among them. So you want to place those common DLLs at single location from where applications can utilize them. Is that right?

Comment: Yes you are right and i resolved this by having all the libraries in a common folder and updated the appconfig of the application with the below

`code`
<configuration>  
   <runtime>  
      <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">  
         <probing privatePath="bin;bin2\subbin;bin3"/>  
      </assemblyBinding>  
   </runtime>  
</configuration>  
`code`

It is working now!!!